# XML Context based bean cannot perform constructor injection : No default constructor found

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I am learning Spring framework (without Spring Boot, in order to understand how it works under the hoods).

I got this beans defined in applicationContext.xml file:

```
    <bean id="connectionXML" class="com.springLearning.ConnectionXML"/>
    <bean id="xmlBasedDAO" class="com.springLearning.XmlBasedDAO">
        <property name="XMLJdbcConnection" ref="connectionXML" />
    </bean>
```

This is my DAO class:

```java
    public class XmlBasedDAO {

        private XMLJdbcConnection XMLJdbcConnection;


        public XMLJdbcConnection getXMLJdbcConnection() {
            return XMLJdbcConnection;
        }

        public void setXMLJdbcConnection(XMLJdbcConnection XMLJdbcConnection) {
            this.XMLJdbcConnection = XMLJdbcConnection;
        }
}
```

This is my ConnectionXML  class:

```java
    public class ConnectionXML implements XMLJdbcConnection {
       @Override
       public void connect() {
           System.out.println("Connected");
       }
   }
```

Which implements this interface :

```java
    public interface XMLJdbcConnection {
        void connect();
    }
```

Now with a setter injection (as shown above), **everything works fine**.

But here is the problem: if I switch to **a defined constructor** injection like so:

```java
    public class XmlBasedDAO {

        private XMLJdbcConnection XMLJdbcConnection;

        public XmlBasedDAO(XMLJdbcConnection XMLJdbcConnection) {
            this.XMLJdbcConnection = XMLJdbcConnection;
        }

        public XMLJdbcConnection getXMLJdbcConnection() {
            return XMLJdbcConnection;
        }
    
}
```

I got this exception:

> Error creating bean with name 'xmlBasedDAO' defined in class path
> resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;
>
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.springLearning.XmlBasedDAO]: No default constructor
> found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
> com.springLearning.XmlBasedDAO.

Why can't I define a constructor in my class with this configuration? Why just a setter injection will work?

I read a lot of questions and the docs too but i did not found an answer for this specific case.

Comment: And next to the constructor did you also change your xml?

Comment: @M.Deinum No, my xml did'nt change ...why should i change the xml after switching to a constructor injection ? (I am new to this kind of stuff....sorry if my question is obvious)

Comment: Which spring version do You use?

Comment: Because you should also let Spring know you want a constructor based injection instead of properties.

Comment: You should change your xml if you switch to the constructor injection because it is written differently. For setters injection you use  propertyName and ref tags to tell spring which dependency you want to inject and when it comes to constructor you should use constructor-arg value. Please look at this link, it is being described nicely there:
https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-bean-constructor-injection-1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring you can perform DI either by using Constructor Injection or by Setter Injection.

`<constructor-arg>` tag is used in constructor injection

`<property>` tag is used in setter injection

You are not changing your xml for constructor injection, you could do this:

```
<bean id="connectionXML" class="com.springLearning.ConnectionXML"/>
<bean id="xmlBasedDAO" class="com.springLearning.XmlBasedDAO">
    <constructor-arg>
     <ref bean="connectionXML"/> 
    </constructor-arg>  
</bean>
```

you can check out this [tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/dependency-injection-in-spring)

Comment: I accepted your answer but could you please improve it with some documentation ?

Comment: Thanks for that....btw : do you know if is there any way to perform a method based injection ?

Comment: check out that link i shared, it also has factory method DI